# 多次元配列のソートarray_multisort関数を使うときに引数の数を動的にしたい

Tags: php

array_multisort関数で画面のチェックボックスがONになっている項目のみ配列データ（$data）をソートしたいのですが、シンプルにできる方法はありますか？

```
$data = array(array('a' => '日本', 'b' => 'たなか', 'c' => '東京都', 'd' => 'A型', 'e' => '60kg', 'f' => '2016-01-03'),
     array('a' => '日本', 'b' => 'さとう', 'c' => '東京都', 'd' => 'O型', 'e' => '58kg', 'f' => '2016-01-03'),
     array('a' => '日本', 'b' => 'やまだ', 'c' => '千葉県', 'd' => 'O型', 'e' => '100kg', 'f' => '2016-01-03'));

foreach($data as $key => $row) {
    $tmp_check_a[$key] = $row['a'];
    $tmp_check_b[$key] = $row['b'];
    $tmp_check_c[$key] = $row['c'];
    $tmp_check_d[$key] = $row['d'];
    $tmp_check_e[$key] = $row['e'];
    $tmp_check_f[$key] = $row['f'];
}

//例1：チェックボックスAとチェックボックスBがONの場合は
array_multisort($tmp_check_a, $tmp_check_b, $data);

//例2：チェックボックスC、D、E、FがONの場合は
array_multisort($tmp_check_c, $tmp_check_d, $tmp_check_e, $tmp_check_f, $data);
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: タイトルに多次元配列とありますが、何が多次元配列なのですか？例えば `$tmp_check_a` は多次元配列 `$data` からa列を抜き出した配列だったりするのでしょうか。 / 引数の数を動的にする方法はありますが、各変数の構造によってはより簡単な方法が使えるかもしれないので、もう少し全体像がつかめるサンプルコードを質問文に載せていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: 失礼しました。サンプルコードを載せました。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.call-user-func-array.php) を使うと任意の関数に渡す引数を配列で指定できます。

```
$checked_a=1;$checked_b=1;$checked_c=0;

$params = array();

if($checked_a) $params[] = &$tmp_check_a;
if($checked_b) $params[] = &$tmp_check_b;
if($checked_c) $params[] = &$tmp_check_c;
// ...

$params[] = &$data;

call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $params);

var_export($data);
```

`array_multisort()` は引数に渡した配列自身を変更するために、[参照渡し](http://php.net/manual/ja/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.by-reference)で引数を受け取ります。これを `call_user_func_array()` で行うため、上記のコードでは `$params` に各変数を代入する際に `&$data` などとして参照を代入するようにしています。

`call_user_func_array()` と `array_multisort()` を組み合わせて二次元配列のソートを行う関数の例が `array_multisort()` のコメント欄に多数投稿されています。こちらも参考になるかと思います。

http://php.net/manual/ja/function.array-multisort.php#usernotes

---

なお、PHP5.5以上であれば [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.array-column.php) で特定の列だけを配列として取り出せます。これを使うと foreach がいらなくなりますし、 `$tmp_check_*` を省略することもできますね。お好みでどうぞ。

```
if($checked_a) $params[] = array_column($data, 'a');
if($checked_b) $params[] = array_column($data, 'b');
if($checked_c) $params[] = array_column($data, 'c');
// ...

$params[] = &$data;
```

Comment: 解決、そして勉強になりました。ありがとうございました！